# Null Pointer Exception when replacing character " with no text then casting value to Float

Tags: java, json, http, get, getjson

I am writing a java program fetching JSON data through HTTP GET methods and it returns the following after I navigate the object tree:

```
{
"year":"2015",
"period":"M03",
"periodName":"March",
"value":"141178",
"footnotes":[{}]
}
```

Now I want to take value and caste it to a float, I tried to do this like such:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

try
{
    JSONObject
    BLSemployment = ( JSONObject ) parser.parse( _RDATA );
    BLSemployment =       ( ( JSONObject ) BLSemployment.get( "Results" ) );

    JSONArray
    BLSemploymentseries = ( ( JSONArray ) BLSemployment.get( "series" ) );

    BLSemployment =       ( ( JSONObject ) BLSemploymentseries.get( 0 ) );
    BLSemploymentseries = ( ( JSONArray ) BLSemployment.get( "data" ) );

    for( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
    {
        BLSemployment = ( (JSONObject) BLSemploymentseries.get( i ) );

        HistoricalNonFarmPayrollData[i] = Float.parseFloat( JSONValue.toJSONString( BLSemployment.get( "value" ) ).replace( "\"" , "" ) );
        HistoricalNonFarmPayrollYear[i] = JSONValue.toJSONString( BLSemployment.get( "year" ) );
        HistoricalNonFarmPayrollMonth[i] = JSONValue.toJSONString( BLSemployment.get( "periodName" ) );
    }
}
catch ( ParseException pe )
{
    System.out.println( pe );
}
```

However Now I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at BLSFramework.getNonFarmPayrolls(playground.java:354)
        at playground.main(playground.java:27)
```

Comment: Split up the line into several lines and see what `null` is or use a debugger!

Comment: I don't understand this part

    HistoricalNonFarmPayrollData[i] = Float.parseFloat( JSONValue.toJSONString( BLSemployment.get( "value" ) ).replace( "\"" , "" ) );

BLSemployment.get( "value" ) seems to return already string. Shouldn't be ?

    HistoricalNonFarmPayrollData[i] = Float.parseFloat( BLSemployment.get( "value" ) );

Comment: you did not put the code that throws the exception. You should post that also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1768232)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: occasionally BLS website doesn't send data for periods of time and I was coding during that period of time.